# Como comparar datas em PHP?

Tags: php, validação, comparação, data

Gostaria de saber qual função eu utilizo para comparar duas datas e retornar a maior.

Eu tenho um formulário para cadastro de RH em que o usuário vai cadastrar suas experiências profissionais sendo que a data de entrada no emprego não pode ser maior que a data de saída por isso eu preciso verificar essa condição e retornar falso.

Alguém teria uma sugestão de como resolver isto eu encontrei algumas soluções mas o formato de data estava em padrão americano o que não me serve.
Att.

Answer (score 37):

Para podermos trabalhar com data antes de tudo temos que ter em mente que o padrão usado é o padrão americano o que nos exige que usamos o formato Ano-Mês-Dia (Ex.: 2013-05-22).

Em nosso exemplo vamos criar um script que compara se a data1 e maior ou igual a data2 e exibindo as mensagens correspondentes.

```
<?php
 $data1 = '2013-05-21';
 $data2 = '2013-05-22';

 // Comparando as Datas
 if(strtotime($data1) > strtotime($data2))
 {
  echo 'A data 1 é maior que a data 2.';
 }
 elseif(strtotime($data1) == strtotime($data2))
 {
  echo 'A data 1 é igual a data 2.';
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'A data 1 é menor a data 2.';
 }
?>
```

Obs.: O comando strtotime gera o timestamp de uma data em formato textual para que possamos trabalhar com as datas.

**Já para a conversão do padrão pode ser feito desta forma:**

```
$dataString = '19/03/2013 11:22';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $dataString);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**E claro deve ser adaptado para sua necessidade.**

Comment: cara....apenas uma questao....se a data tiver no formato `YYYY-MM-DD` voce nao precisa usar `strtotime` a comparação já dará certo pela simples ordem numérica.

Answer (score 22):

Uma maneira rapida e facil de se fazer isso é utilizando a classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) junto com o metodo [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

```
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

/** Assumido que $dataEntrada e $dataSaida estao em formato dia/mes/ano */
$data1 = DateTime::createFromFormat ('d/m/Y', $dataEntrada, $timeZone);
$data2 = DateTime::createFromFormat ('d/m/Y', $dataSaida, $timeZone);

/** Testa se sao validas */
if (!($data1 instanceof DateTime)) {
  echo 'Data de entrada invalida!!';
}

if (!($data2 instanceof DateTime)) {
  echo 'Data de saida invalida!!';
}

/** Compara as datas normalmente com operadores de comparacao < > = e !=*/
if ($data1 > $data2) {
  echo 'Data de entrada maior que data de saida!';
}

if ($data1 < $data2) {
  echo 'Data de entrada menor que data de saida!';
}
```

Neste exemplo utilizei a classe [DateTimeZone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) para garantir que as datas estejam na mesma zona temporal, evitando problemas de horario.

Comment: Cara, você salvou minha vida kkkkk
Mais um UP pra você!

Answer (score 5):

Além do que o Otto já disse, você pode fazer isso de modo menos específico (que foi o que achei que queria, visto que escreveu que não servia padrão americano).
Caso você salve a data com traços ou delimitadores no meio desta, basta usar preg_replace(ou qualquer outra função que cumpra isso) na string para remover o caractere que separa ano, mês e dia. Se não usa vá direto pro próximo passo...

Depois de remover os caracteres delimitadores:

```
<?php
$data_entrada = "01022014";
$dia_entrada = substr($data_entrada, 0, 2);
$mes_entrada = substr($data_entrada, 2, 2);
$ano_entrada = substr($data_entrada, 4, 4);
$data_saida = "01022014";
$dia_saida = substr($data_saida, 0, 2);
$mes_saida = substr($data_saida, 2, 2);
$ano_saida = substr($data_saida, 4, 4);


if ($ano_saida > $ano_entrada) {
    echo "A data de saída é posterior a de entrada";
} elseif ($ano_saida == $ano_entrada) {
// CASO ANO IGUAL
    if ($mes_saida > $mes_entrada) {
        echo "A data de saída é posterior a de entrada";
    } elseif ($mes_saida == $mes_entrada) {
        // INICIO CASO MES IGUAL
       if ($dia_saida > $dia_entrada) {
        echo "A data de saída é posterior a de entrada";
       } elseif ($dia_saida == $dia_entrada) {
        echo "As datas de saída e entrada são  iguais";
} elseif ($dia_saida < $dia_entrada) {
    echo "A data de saída é anterior a de entrada";
} // FIM CASO MES IGUAL
} elseif ($mes_saida < $mes_entrada) {
    echo "A data de saída é anterior a de entrada";
}
// FIM DO CASO ANO IGUAL
} else {
    echo "A data de saída é anterior a de entrada";
}

?>
```

Nota: Se necessário, lembre-se de retirar espaços em branco depois e antes da string usando `trim()` ou outras...

Comment: -1 o PHP tem várias formas de trabalhar com datas. `substr` ou `preg_replace` são bastante desnecessários nesse caso.