# Comparação de datas com strtotime

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$data = date("Y-m-d");
$dataTr = implode(preg_match("~\/~", $data_vencimento) == 0 ? "/" : "-", array_reverse(explode(preg_match("~\/~", $data_vencimento) == 0 ? "-" : "/", $data_vencimento)));

    if (strtotime($data) > strtotime($data_vencimento)):
        echo "<font color='red'>$dataTr - Vencida</font>";
    elseif(strtotime($data) == strtotime($data_vencimento)):
        echo "<font color='yellow'>$dataTr</font>";
    else:
        echo "<font color='green'>$dataTr</font>";
    endif;
```

O meu intuito era o de que caso a `$data`, que seria hoje fosse maior que a data de vencimento, a data deveria ficar ressaltada em vermelho, se fosse igual a hoje ficasse em amarelo e se fosse menor que ficasse em verde, mas por algum motivo isso não está acontecendo, e todas datas estão ficando verdes, sendo que há datas já vencidas. Gostaria de saber onde está o meu erro.
P.S: As datas estão sendo comparadas no formato Americano AAAA/MM/DD, de acordo com dados dessa [pergunta do SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33469/como-comparar-datas-em-php).

Comment: Como que está o valor de `$data_vencimento`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa nem usar expressão regular:

```
$data = date("Y-m-d"); //Data de Hoje
$dataVencimento = '2017-03-20';

if (strtotime($data) > strtotime($data_vencimento)):
    echo "<font color='red'>$dataVencimento - Vencida</font>";
elseif(strtotime($data) == strtotime($data_vencimento)):
    echo "<font color='yellow'>$dataVencimento</font>";
else:
    echo "<font color='green'>$dataVencimento</font>";
endif;
```

Tenha certeza que as datas estão vindo com o separador **-** (traço) e não **/** (barra). Caso você use **/** o PHP não conseguirá fazer a conversão para `timestamp`, assim, não deixando você fazer a comparação.