# Como verificar se Data X é mais nova que Data Y?

Tags: php

Tenho as seguintes variáveis:
`$dt_local`: que está guardando valor do BD;
`$dt_remoto`: que está guardando valor de uma fonte externa;
Até aqui tudo ótimo, preciso comparar as duas e manter a data mais atual no BD, ambas as variáveis estão vindo como `String`.

Como posso resolver de forma mais rápida e simples?

Comment: Relacionada ou até repetida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33469/como-comparar-datas-em-php

Comment: qual o formato da data? dd/mm/yyyy?

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que você possua essas datas em algum formato definido, você pode utilizar a classe [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php) do PHP:

```
$dt_local = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '03-04-2017');
$dt_remoto = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '01-04-2017');

if ($dt_local > $dt_remoto) {
    echo "Local é mais recente", PHP_EOL;
} else if ($dt_local < $dt_remoto) {
    echo "Remoto é mais recente", PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "Datas são iguais", PHP_EOL;
}
```

A saída seria: `Local é mais recente`.

Se a data poderá estar em qualquer padrão definido na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.formats.date.php) do PHP, utilize o próprio construtor da classe:

```
$dt_local = new DateTime('03-04-2017');
$dt_remoto = new DateTime('01-04-2017');

if ($dt_local > $dt_remoto) {
    echo "Local é mais recente", PHP_EOL;
} else if ($dt_local < $dt_remoto) {
    echo "Remoto é mais recente", PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "Datas são iguais", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Em teoria, qualquer formato previsto na tabela abaixo será aceito pela aplicação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mas como é que se joga as datas vindas de post dentro da função DateTime?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo algo como `$dt_local = new DateTime($_POST['dt_local'])`.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo O que aconteceu?

Comment: não li as notações localizadas e estava entrando com as datas no formato errado e daí estava dando erro.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de se verificar é usando a função `max ( $valor1 , $valor2 )` (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)

onde $valor1 e $valor2 são valores compatíveis no formato dd/mm/aaaa ou dd-mm-aaaa.

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.max.php)

```
<?php
function inverteData($data){
    if(count(explode("/",$data)) > 1){
        return implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$data)));
    }elseif(count(explode("-",$data)) > 1){
        return implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$data)));
    }
}

if  (($_POST["dt_local"])&&($_POST["dt_remoto"])){

    $dt_local=inverteData($_POST["dt_local"]);  

    $dt_remoto=inverteData($_POST["dt_remoto"]);

    if ($dt_local!=$dt_remoto){
       $maior = max(array($dt_local,$dt_remoto));
       echo inverteData($maior);
    }else{
       echo "as datas são iguais";;
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: Apenas um detalhe: utilizando `max`, a data retornada em `$maior` seria `05-04-2017`, pois tratando-se de *string*, é comparado de forma alfabética caractere a caractere. Neste caso, sendo o primeiro caractere igual, ao verificar o segundo, o PHP considera 5 maior que 3, retornando a primeira data como maior, ou seja, nem chega a verificar o restante da *string*. Para este método funcionar bem, a data deverá estar no formato `Y-m-d`, assim ele verificaria o mês antes de verificar o dia, não considerando o dia 05/04 maior que 03/05.

Comment: pronto editei a resposta, duas cabeças pensam melhor que uma né não?