# Comparação de datas - PHP

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte comparação:

```
# Verifica se está em tempo habil para concluir a transacao
if($transacao->data_expira <= date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." 000000"){
    echo "Ainda é permitido pagar"; 
} else {
    echo "Esta cobrança não pode ser mais paga!";
}
```

> Onde $transcao->data_expira é = 2017-10-05 15:42:54.000000

```
Data Atual: 2017-10-04 19:14:20
Data Expira: 2017-10-05 15:42:54
```

Neste caso, teria de ser permitido o pagamento.
Como eu posso fazer esta comparação de forma correta?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33469/como-comparar-datas-em-php

Comment: `$transacao->data_expira` é do tipo `DateTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Levando em consideração que `$transacao->data_expira` é do tipo `DateTime`, você pode comparar usando a função `->diff()`, veja:

```
if ($transacao->data_expira->diff(new DateTime("today")) >= 0) {
    echo "Ainda é permitido pagar";
} else {
    echo "Esta cobrança não pode ser mais paga!";
}
```

Caso `$transacao->data_expira` não seja do tipo `DateTime`, inicie uma nova instância para então compara-las.

```
$data_expira = new DateTime($transcao->data_expira); // 2017-10-05 15:42:54
$hoje = new DateTime("today"); // 2017-10-04
$intervalo = $data_expira->diff($hoje);
echo $interval->format("%a days"); // 1 days
```

[Veja funcionando no ideone](https://ideone.com/A5NF6i)

Comment: É possível, mas deu erro. Call to a member function diff()

Comment: O formato é com data e hora

Comment: coloquei explicação de como iniciar o `DateTime` @AndréBaill

Answer (score 1):

Você pode comparar o timestamp das datas assim:

```
if (strtotime($numerical." ".$day." of ".date("F")) < time()) {
    // Mais velho
} else {
    // Mais novo
}
```

Antes convertendo a data para str quebrando a mesma.

**Timestamp**

Uma marca temporal (ou estampa de tempo) é uma cadeia de caracteres denotando a hora ou data que certo evento ocorreu. A cadeia é geralmente apresentada num formato consistente, permitindo fácil comparação entre duas marcas temporais distintas.

Elas são padronizadas pela Organização Internacional para Padronização (ISO) através da ISO 8601.

Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_temporal