# O que há de errado neste código?

Tags: php

Eis o código:

```
$aniversario = $_POST['aniversario'];
    $dataAtual = date("Y/m/dd");
    $noRobot = $dataAtual - $aniversario;
    echo $noRobot;
```

Eis o erro:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\toqve\no_robot.php on line 18.

Obrigado a quem responder.

Comment: o que tem na linha 18?

Comment: precisa ver o formato dos números para fazer a subtração

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33469/como-comparar-datas-em-php

Comment: São 2 datas iguais ?

Comment: Outra relação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/como-calcular-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-duas-datas/70

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está fazendo a diferença de datas de forma direta, como se fossem números, e isto não é correto.

Tenha certeza que ambas as variáveis contendo data estão no mesmo formato.
Então use a Classe DateTime(data) e faça a diferença entre as mesmas.

Então tente:

```
$post_aniversario = '11/05/2000';

$aniversario = new DateTime();
$aniversario = $aniversario->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $post_aniversario);
$data_atual = new DateTime();
$diff = $aniversario->diff($data_atual);
print_r($diff); // or $diff->days
```

Resultado:

DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => x
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => x
)

Ou ainda usando datediff

```
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```

[Explicação date_diff](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_date_date_diff.asp)

Comment: Na linha 18 tem o $noRobot = $dataAtual - $aniversario; e são datas diferentes. Uma vem do formulário e outra é criada pelo data atual. Eu não entendi a sua explicação #LeoNogueira. Estou na verdade com o sinal de menos querendo ver o resultado entra as duas datas. O código chega a me dar o resultado, que aqui no meu caso foi 37, porém ele exibe esse erro.

Comment: Alterei a minha resposta por completo para tentar ser mais claro.

Comment: Obrigado @LeoNogueira, mas copiei e colei sua resposta e não deu certo também. Apareceu outro erro. O que estou querendo fazer é pegar o conteúdo da variável aniversário que é enviado de um formulário e subtrair pela data atual.

Comment: Tente agora, inseri o formato da data de aniversário. Altere o formato se necessário.

Comment: aparece isso aqui DateInterval Object ( [y] => 17 [m] => 4 [d] => 23 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [f] => 0.763454 [weekday] => 0 [weekday_behavior] => 0 [first_last_day_of] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 6355 [special_type] => 0 [special_amount] => 0 [have_weekday_relative] => 0 [have_special_relative] => 0 )

Comment: Troque $post_aniversario = '11/05/2000'; pelo seu $POST, isso é um objeto php com diferença completa das datas. y -> anos, m -> meses, d -> dias, h -> horas, etc

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66601/discussion-between-leo-nogueira-and-francis-vagner-da-luz).