# Não consigo comparar datas com DateTime() em PHP

Tags: datetime, data

Tenho um formulário onde envio a data 1-4-2017 em cada campo separado(dia, mês e ano). O código a baixo recebe a data normalmente, mas quando chega na parte da comparação ela não ocorre, o resultado deveria ser a exibição de uma mensagem de erro porque a data que o formulário envia é menor do que a data que está na variável `$range_start`, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<?php

    //cria um objeto datetime para seis meses atrás
    $range_start = new DateTime("6 months ago");

    //cria um objeto DateTime para hoje
    $range_end = new DateTime();

    //há um ano de quatro dígitos em $_POST['year']
    $input['day'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'day', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options'=>array('min_range'=>1, 'max_range'=>31)));
    $input['month'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'month', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options'=>array('min_range'=>1, 'max_range'=>12)));
    $input['year'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'year', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options'=>array('min_range'=>1900, 'max_range'=>2100)));

    print $input['year'].'-'.$input['month'].'-'.$input['day'];

    if($input['year'] && $input['month'] && $input['day'] && checkdate($input['month'], $input['day'], $input['year'])){
        $submitted_date = new DateTime($input['year'].'-'.$input['month'].'-'.$input['day']);
       print "<br/>".$submitted_date->format("Y-m-d");
        if(($range_start> $submitted_date)||($range_end< $submitted_date)){
            $errors[] = 'Please choose a date less than six months old.';
        }
    }else{
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid date';
    }

    if($erros){
        foreach($errors as $msg){
            print $msg."\n".$input['day'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como comparar datas em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33469/como-comparar-datas-em-php)

Comment: Opções de como comparar datas na pergunta citada é o que não falta.

Comment: `if($erros)` não deveria ser `if($errors)` ? E se a ideia é saber se existe o melhor é usar `isset`. Na comparação `($range_end< $submitted_date)` também está trocada pois `$range_end` deve ser maior que `$submitted_date`.