# Comparar data e hora em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho as seguintes datas:

```
data atual: 2018-02-11 20:14:40
data expiracao: 2018-02-12 19:57:10
```

Eu preciso fazer uma comparação entre uma e outra.

```
if($dados['transacao']->data_expira <= date("Y-m-d H:i:s")){
    echo "Ainda está dentro do prazo";
} else {
    echo "Você não pode mais efetuar o pagamento desta cobrança.";
}
```

Pela lógica, estaria certo, porém, não funciona. Ele insiste em me dizer que estou fora do prazo. Já estive utilizando o exemplo postado aqui neste link do SPO:

> [Como comparar datas em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33469/como-comparar-datas-em-php)

O que eu posso fazer para ajustar?

Comment: Utilize `strtotime($dados['transacao']->data_expira) <= time()`

Comment: @RpgBoss Exatamente por isso que eu coloquei que já usei o exemplo e não deu certo.

Comment: Traga com `echo` ou `print_r` o resultado **$dados['transacao']->data_expira** pra ver se realmente é uma data ou uma String.

Comment: o que retorna isso: $dados['transacao']->data_expira?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic retorna a data de expiração, neste formato: string(19) "2018-02-12 19:57:10"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

é bem simples na verdade

```
$data_transacao= strtotime($dados['transacao']->data_expira);
$hoje= strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

if($data_transacao<= $hoje) { 
   echo "Ainda está dentro do prazo"; 
} else {
   echo "Você não pode mais efetuar o pagamento desta cobrança.";
}
```

Comment: Então, ai que tá, não deu certo... por mais simples que seja, não funcionou, e o formato das duas está como string.. : string(19) "2018-02-12 19:57:10" string(19) "2018-02-12 14:25:52"

Comment: por isso q estou transformando em data utilizando o strtotime. Acabei de testar aqui e tudo ok.