# Somar valor a uma data com PHP

Tags: php

Estou com um problema ao somar uma data que vem do banco de dados que vem da seguinte forma:
Ex.: 10/05/2018 17:48:27
Estou utilizando o seguinte método para para somar dias a essa data:

```
date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime('+10 days', strtotime('10/05/2018 17:48:27')));
```

Porém o resulta do que obtenho é esse:
10-01-1970 16:00:00

Verifiquei que quando o formato da data é com "-" (ou seja... 10-05-2018 17:48:27) ao invés de "/" a soma dá certo.

Minha pergunta é, como seria fazer essa soma dar certo com o padrão que recebo do banco de dados, como no exemplo "10/05/2018 17:48:27".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É sempre mais seguro nesses casos usar `DateTime::createFromFormat`, já que  é você quem diz para o PHP qual é o formato que deve ser usado para fazer o parser da data.

Veja:

```
 $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '10/05/2018 17:48:27');
```

Para acrescentar os dias, basta usar `modify`

```
 $datetime->modify('+10 days');
```

Para exibir use  `format`

```
 echo $datetime->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

**Alguns comentários sobre o que você colocou na pergunta**

> Porém o resulta do que obtenho é esse: 10-01-1970 16:00:00

Geralmente, quando o PHP não consegue processar uma data corretamente, a data definida é essa. Em alguns casos, a classe `DateTime` até acusa erros na sintaxe da data (no caso, acredito ser o parser usado internamente do `strtotime` que faça essa verificação);

Se você ver [esse exemplo](https://ideone.com/B5rkFo) onde eu uso a função `date_parse`, poderá perceber como é que o PHP entendeu a sua string de data.

Código do Exemplo:

```
 print_r(date_parse ('10/05/2018 17:48:27'));
```

A saída é:

```
array(12) {
  ["year"]=>
  int(2018)
  ["month"]=>
  int(10)
  ["day"]=>
  int(5)
  ["hour"]=>
  int(17)
  ["minute"]=>
  int(48)
  ["second"]=>
  int(27)
  ["fraction"]=>
  float(0)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["is_localtime"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Repare que o PHP interpreta o `05` como `dia` e o `10` como mês.

> Verifiquei que quando o formato da data é com "-" (ou seja... 10-05-2018 17:48:27) ao invés de "/" a soma dá certo.

Sim, funções como `strtotime` e `date_parse` ou a classe `DateTime` do PHP têm uma [lista de formatos pré-definidos para fazer a interpretação data](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.formats.date.php), no qual o formato que geralmente é usado no Brasil não faz parte desta lista.

Como eu disse anteriormente, basta usar `createFromFormat` que seu problema é resolvido.

Comment: Excelente! Muito obrigado deu muito certo! Obrigado pelas explicações.

Comment: @Carlos dá uma olhada na edição. O `date_parse` pode ser seu amigo nessas horas.

Comment: E como fazer comparações?

Comment: @Carlos aí já é outra pergunta. Mas no PHP é fácil. Basta você fazer `DateTime > DateTime('+10 days')` por exemplo. É claro que você vai usar os objetos que você tiver criado pelo `createFromFormat`.

Comment: @Carlos veja [Como comparar datas em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33469/como-comparar-datas-em-php)