# comparar data do banco com data atual LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

Como eu comparo a data `created_at` com a data atual e mostro os apontamentos com essa data

#### index.php

```
@if(\Carbon\Carbon::create($data)->format('d-m-Y') === \Carbon\Carbon::create($creat)->format('d-m-Y'))
    @foreach ($hoje as $hj)
     {{$hj>created_at}} //mostre os apontamentos de hoje
    @endforeach
@else
    teste
@endif
```

#### Controller

```
 $data = Carbon::today();
 $creat = Apontamento::get('created_at');
 $hoje = Apontamento::all();
```

Comment: Então são poucas informações, não tem como responder!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic mas não deu para entender ? eu queria saber como comparo duas data, uma do banco e data atual, estou usando o carbon, mas nao estou conseguindo

Comment: Compara datas em PHP tem vários exemplos no site, já pesquisou ???

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33469/como-comparar-datas-em-php um exemplo!

Comment: sim.. se viu ai no index qe postei até na function usei new data(), DataTime('NOW') e não consegui...

Comment: Porque não se deve ter regra ai na `View` ... você pode mandar um status para a sua `view` se a data for satisfeita. Como a gente não sabe o que é para fazer fica complicado.

Comment: eu vi esse, tentei fazer mas para laravel.. não consegui... @VirgilioNovic

Comment: return view('home', compact('cliente', 'apontamento', 'aptFinalizado', 'aptPendente', 'data', 'creat', 'hoje')); @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Primeiro se tem que aprender PHP e depois usar Laravel. Porque o Framework é feito em PHP e com as informações do banco você já tem uma comparação.

Comment: E o que está na sua `View` não pode ser comparado assim, precisa ser igual está nesse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33469/como-comparar-datas-em-php ou até outros aqui

Comment: @VirgilioNovic vou dar uma olhada, mto obrigado

Answer (score 0):

@Bruno, antes de tudo compare essas datas no *controller* e apenas passe para a *view* o que você precisa já comparado.

Da forma que você está fazendo essa tela pode demorar bastante para ser renderizada, caso tenha **20mil** dados, por exemplo.

Então você você deve primeiro filtrar os apontamentos pela data atual e depois passar a variável já com os dados filtrados para a *view*

### Como filtrar os dados em laravel

Para isso você vai utilizar o ***[Eloquent - Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)*** facilitando muito nossa vida

**Exemplo**:

```
$hoje = Apontamento::whereDate('created_at', today())->get();
```

O `->get()` é para transformar o seu *Eloquent Builder* em um *[Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections)* para poder tratar os dados individualmente na sua *view*

Comment: obrigado, vou dar uma olhada.